# Microsoft Pivot JIT Collections

Tags: deepzoom, pivotviewer

I'm attempting to implement a Microsoft Pivot viewer within my application, I've decided that a cross between a JIT collection and Linked Collection is the best case however I'm having a few issues.

The images for the collection are generated by a C# Windows Service that runs overnight generating new images that are required.

The CXML file is then generated dynamically when the user request the data using a custom HttpHandler.

The issue is that with 10000+ items my development machine runs out of memory whilst trying to turn the generated png/jpg images into a DZC.

Is there a tool available that I could use to turn the images that I have into DZI images. I've looked at the Deep Zoom Composer, but I really need something that I can run overnight to convert the images, currently I have about 45,000 images that I need to convert, the Composer just locks up trying to do anything with that amount of images.

Ideally I would like to be able to create the DZI images directly using the service instead of creating png/jpg images first.

Comment: I think you should consider taking a closer look at your memory issue while converting.  eliminating the memory issue should put you where you need to be without having to change you approach.  code sample?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft's tools to convert the images on the server, its not my code which is why I'm looking to find a tool that can convert them offline instead of JIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i could not see if you already had these tools or not but here goes nothing:

http://www.silverlight.net/archives/whitepapers/deep-zoom-tools

if you use these tools you can preprocess the images and use them later in your collection. if you need dynamic images you might want to take a look at the Silverligh 5 RC (of which the latest version includes the new pivotviewer). this new version converts your xaml into dzi at runtime and is a really cool control!

Comment: Thank you for information about Silverlight 5, that sounds like it will be exactly what we need.